# MVC parameterless action methods with $.ajax does not return results

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, css

I got 2 dropdown list boxes and I am loading values into first dropdown list and depending on its selection I load values to 2nd one via same action method via ajax

below is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    $("#ddlOrgs").change(function () {
    var listSite = $("#_site");
    var SelctedOrgCode = $("#ddlOrgs").val();
    alert(SelctedOrgCode);
    if (SelctedOrgCode != 0) {               

        var url = '@Url.Action("GetSites","FilterMenu")';               
        $.ajax({               
            url : url,
            type: 'POST',
            tempdata:{},
            data: JSON.stringify(tempdata),                    
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        })
        .done(function (data) {   
        var sitesDropdown = $("#ddlSites");                                      
        var list = data;
        $.each(list, function (index, item) {
                sitesDropdown.append('<option value?+item.SiteCode+?="">' + item.SiteName + '</option>');
                alert(item);
         });

      })
      .fail(function(xhr){
           alert('failed');
           alert(xhr.responseText); 
     });
            }             
        });
    });
```

My Controller action methods

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Client> LoadFiltersX(constants.ClientType clientType)
{  
         List<Client> Clients = new List<Client>();
         Client thisClient = new Client();

         _client.UserName = this.UserName;

         ClientRepository ClientRepo = new ClientRepository(_client);

         switch (clientType)
         {
             case constants.ClientType.ORG:
                 Clients = ClientRepo.GetClientInformation(constants.ClientType.ORG);
                 //HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT,thisClient);
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT, _client);
                 break;
             case constants.ClientType.CLIENT:
                 Clients = ClientRepo.GetClientInformation(constants.ClientType.CLIENT);
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT, thisClient);
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT, _client);
                 break;
             case constants.ClientType.SITE:
                 Clients = ClientRepo.GetClientInformation(constants.ClientType.SITE);
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT, thisClient);
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT, _client);
                 break;
             case constants.ClientType.SYSTEM:
                 Clients = ClientRepo.GetClientInformation(constants.ClientType.SYSTEM);
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT, thisClient);
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT, _client);
                 break;
         }
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(constants.SESSION_CLIENT, _client);

         return Clients;
     }








      [HttpPost]              
         public JsonResult GetSites()
         {             
              return Json( LoadFiltersX(constants.ClientType.SITE), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

          }
```

in my repository I returned List collection as follows

```
public List<Client> GetClientInformation(constants.ClientType clientType)
        {
            List<Client> Clients = new List<Client>();
            Repository Repo = new Repository();

            Paralist.Clear();
            SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("OrgCode", _client.OrgCode);

            Paralist.Add(p);
            p = new SqlParameter("SiteCode", _client.SiteCode);
            Paralist.Add(p);

            p = new SqlParameter("ClientCode", _client.ClientCode);
            Paralist.Add(p);

            p = new SqlParameter("UserName", _client.UserName);
            Paralist.Add(p);

            try
            {
                SqlCommand com = Repo.GetCommand("uspStructureBuilderFilterGET", Paralist);
                Client AddingClient = null;
                using (IDataReader ClientReader = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (ClientReader.Read())
                    {                         
                        switch(clientType)
                        {
                            case constants.ClientType.ORG:                            
                                AddingClient = new Client(){ OrgCode=ClientReader["OrgID"].ToString(), OrgName = ClientReader["Description"].ToString() };
                                break;                           

                            case constants.ClientType.SITE:

                                AddingClient = new Client(){ OrgCode = _client.OrgCode, OrgName = _client.ClientName, SiteCode=ClientReader["SiteID"].ToString(), SiteName = ClientReader["Description"].ToString() };
                                break;

                            case constants.ClientType.CLIENT:
                                AddingClient = new Client(){ OrgCode = _client.OrgCode, OrgName = _client.ClientName, SiteCode= _client.SiteCode, SiteName = _client.SiteName, ClientCode=ClientReader["ClientID"].ToString(), ClientName = ClientReader["Description"].ToString() };
                                break;

                            case constants.ClientType.SYSTEM:
                                AddingClient = new Client(){OrgCode = _client.OrgCode, OrgName = _client.ClientName, SiteCode= _client.SiteCode, SiteName = _client.SiteName, ClientCode = _client.ClientCode, ClientName = _client.ClientName, SystemId=ClientReader["SystemID"].ToString(), SystemName = ClientReader["System"].ToString() };
                                break;
                        }
                        AddingClient.UserName = _client.UserName;                        
                        Clients.Add(AddingClient);
                    }
                }                
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                ErrorLogger el = new ErrorLogger();
                el.AddErrorToLogger("ClientRepository", "GetClientInformation", e.Message, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                throw e;
            }

            return Clients;
        }
```

View part (located in Layout file)

```
@if (Session.Count > 0 && Session["UserName"].ToString().Length > 0)
{
    Client Client = new StB.Models.Client();
    ClientRepository cr = new ClientRepository(Client);
    //FilterMenu fm = new FilterMenu(Client);
    FilterMenuController fmc = new FilterMenuController(Client);

     <div class="DrawEmptyRow"></div>


    <div class="navbar">
        @*<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">*@
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline ListItemHeight">
            <li>Org: @Html.DropDownList("ddlOrgs", new SelectList(fmc.GetAllOrganizations.ToList(), "OrgCode", "OrgName", String.Empty), "-- Select Organisation --")</li>           
            <li id="_site">Site: <select id="ddlSites" name="ddlSites">
   <option value="">Select Site </option>
</select></li>

            <li>Exclude Decom: @Html.CheckBox("exDcom")</li>
            <li>Exclude No Equip: @Html.CheckBox("ExNoEQuip")</li>
        </ul>          
    </div>        
}
```

When I call No results returned and console displays error "tempdata undefned". This method does not pass any parameters. Each dropdown list has same client list but first takes 'ORG' enum and 2nd takes 'SITE' enum. so I passed it for each method. I want to get List to populate dropdown list. I load 1st dropdwon list successfully via normal Action method in Controller. but problem occurs in ajax method. Please help me as I am stuck where its getting wrong. Am i supposed to change it to 'GET'? then ajax method fails and displays html page with css values. Anybody please help me as I am struggling to get this. Thanks for any help in Advance.

thanks 
tpk

Comment: are you hitting the right action method? ajax call says: LoadFiltersX  but you have pasted "LoadFiltersX" as http post action method.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call remove "tempdata" variable if you don't have any value for it.

```
        $.ajax({               
            url : url,
            type: 'POST',                
            data: {}, // Pass the paramaters for MVC action method here...                    
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        })
```

url = '@Url.Action("GetSites","FilterMenu")';  : Note: this won't work if you move your javascript to a seperate javascript file. Use relative url "/Controller/ActionMethod".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with $.getJSON using JsonResult Return method

```
  var url = "/FilterMenu/GetAllSites"
  $.getJSON(url, function (response) {           
            sites.empty(); // remove any existing options
            $.each(response, function (index, item) {         
                sites.append('<option value='+item.SiteCode +'>' + item.SiteName + '</option>')
            });
```

Yes you're correct I used @Url.Action method but return error saying "cannot find location 404 error" when I hit the link url loads in browser as follows
(this was another issue i got)
http://localhost:10345/**Home**/FilterMenu/GetAllSites (note new new link is adding to Home Controller part)

when I give full url (like this 'http://localhost:10345/FilterMenu/GetAllSites and hit enter it will jump into correct action method and returned results.

I realized additional /Home part makes the error. Now I changed into relative url like you said and works. in fact I gave same as before but none works. but now $getJSON solved issues. Thanks for replying me and very much appreciated.